# SQL CASE based on specific values

Tags: sql, mysql, case

I am trying to understand SQL better and have run into a problem when it comes to key-value pairs (I think there is a better term for this, but am not sure).

| Contract | Contract Type | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Contract 1 | Type 1 | x |  |
| Contract 1 | Type 2 |  | x |
| Contract 2 | Type 1 | x |  |
| Contract 2 | Type 2 | x |  |

I apologize if this example isn't clear. I know there might be a way to set up this table better, however this is just an example I made up.

I am trying to create an SQL query that checks whether contracts are set up correctly. As an example, Contract 1 is set up correctly, as there is an x in column1 when it says 'type 1', and an x in column2 when it says 'type 2'.

However, I am unsure how to write the CASE statement for Contract 2, as it requires checking each contract individually to see if either row has an 'x' in the correct places.

So far I've written the CASE statements for when there's no 'x's in either row, and 'x's in both:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Contract,
   Table1.ContractType,
   Table1.Column1,
   Table1.Column2,
   Table1.Site
   Table1.Date,
   CASE
      WHEN Column1 <> 'x' AND Column2 <> 'x' THEN 'Error'
      WHEN Column1 = 'x' AND Column2 = 'x' THEN 'Error'
   END AS 'Results'
FROM...
JOIN...

WHERE Contract IN (
     SELECT Contract
     FROM Table1 
     WHERE ContractType IN ('Type1','Type2','Type3') AND 
         Site = 'Site 1' AND 
         Contract HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ContractType) >= 2
) AND Date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY Contract
```

How do I check per Contract that there is x in Column1 for the first row and check that there is an x in Column2 for the second row?

Thank you!

EDIT: Edited in the 'full query', with some abstraction as to not show real data.
Something that I might have poorly explained: Technically, it would be okay if Column2 has an 'x' in a Type1 row and vice versa. The important part is that for each Contract, there's an 'x' in both columns, via different rows.

Comment: Is the `Contract` column meant to be a key-column?

Comment: Yes, the Contract is the key. I would like to say 'for each contract', check if the first row Column1 has an X, check if second row Column2 has an x, then it is correct.

Comment: Your sample data shows non-unique values in the `Contact` column, therefore it cannot be a key column.

Comment: @Dai, reality is that it looks like Contract + Contract Type is the key, not just Contract on its own.  If OP is only new to SQL then may not completely understand the concept

Comment: @MichaelDahle, you are kind of on the right starting track with a CASE expression, however you haven't included your full query, so we can't tell where you might be going astray with the query in its entirety.  The reality is, in instances like this, that you need to tell SQL how the different rows relate to each other (ie. rows with the same "Contract" value, but a different "Contract Type").  I'd suggest that you update your question with your full query so that others can give you the required guidance

Comment: What do you mean by this: "However, I am unsure how to write the CASE statement for Contract 2, as it requires checking each contract individually to see if either row has an 'x' in the correct places." Whats mean "it requires checking each contract individually"?

Comment: Apologies if I did not explain this very well: Each Contract needs to have an 'x' in both columns, Columns 1 and 2. However, the 'x's must be in different columns. To check if a contract is correct, you'd need to look at every row that contract has, to see if the 'x' values are in different columns.

Comment: are there 3 columns or 2 ?

Comment: 4? If you count the Contract and ContractType as columns? The other columns being called Column1 and Column2 are because I lack imagination.

Comment: @MichaelDahle - how many different "Contract Type"s (and how many different corresponding columns for each contract type) do you actually have?  The best solution may be a little bit dependent on this

Comment: Let's say there are 5 different 'Contract Types'. There is only Column1 and Column2 though. So even if the Contract Types were Type 3 and Type 5, they'd still need to have the 'x's in Column 1, Column 2 in different rows.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new requirements (which I believe are as follows

- Each row must have a value in column1 or column2
- Contract type can not be repeated
- there should be 2 rows
- based on code this may need to be 3 or more columns in the first bullet

Here is the code to solve:

```
 SELECT 
    -- ... all the columns for the data you need
    COUNT(Column1 = 'x') as col1cnt,
    COUNT(Column2 = 'x') as col2cnt,
    COUNT(ContactType) as ctrows
 FROM tablenameyoudidnotsay
 GROUP BY Contract
 WHERE col1cnt = 1 and col2cnt = 1 and ctrows = 2
```

Note -- based on the query above if you wanted the other columns that are not in the group by you would need to make this a subquery joined to the main query on Contract -- to only pull the correct ones OR add a not around the where clauses to only pull the bad ones.

Comment: I may not understand the problem -- is the issue that you need to have two rows for each contact -- one for type 1 and one for type 2 AND have values in the column1 and column2?

Comment: Table name is the best ;)

Comment: Sorry, I probably used a horrible example to explain this issue. I'm pulling every contract that has more than one type of Contract Type, and this contract in the example has Type 1 and Type 2. I'm checking to see if the contract is correct. Contracts are only correct when they have an 'x' in column 1 in one row, and an 'x' in column 2 in the other. So as another commenter said, I think I need to do some form of aggregation since the 'x' values are on more than one row.

Comment: @MichaelDahle -- see above -- I listed my understanding of the requirements.

Comment: Thanks @LordF -- has become my standard on this site -- even had to use "anothertableyoudidnotname" as a joining table once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP BY` to define groups of rows, and then a apply `CASE` clause to check whether contracts are set up correctly or not :

`WHERE` clause will filter out unnecessary data.

`MAX(column1) = 'x' and MAX(column2) = 'x'` to make sure both columns having value `x`

Since you are searching for the combination of 2 contract types, `COUNT(DISTINCT Contract_Type) = 2` will limit your results to only Contracts having the two types.

```
SELECT Contract, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Contract_Type ) = 2 
                 AND MAX(column1) = 'x' 
                 AND MAX(column2) = 'x'
            THEN 'OK' 
            ELSE 'NOK' 
       END AS results
FROM mytable
WHERE Contract_Type = 'Type 1' OR
      Contract_Type = 'Type 2'
GROUP BY Contract;
```

Your table schema is "EAV" or Entity-Attribute-Value. This is a common schema for applications to use if the number of attributes per entity is unknown or volatile

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7YBZ2peP)